# Setting up Custom HandlerExceptionResolver in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, exception, message

I am trying to override WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.configureHandlerExceptionResolvers() and provide my own ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver to Spring MVC. The motive behind this is to provide Custom Content Negotiation in such a way that if the user requests for any garbage in "Accept" header, I can return him a JSON response with "media not supported exception". I was partially able to acheive the configuration using the bellow setup.

```
@Override
public void configureHandlerExceptionResolvers(List<HandlerExceptionResolver> exceptionResolvers) {
    ContentNegotiationManager contentNegotiationManager = new ContentNegotiationManager(new ErrorContentNegotiation());
    ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver = exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver();
    exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.setContentNegotiationManager(contentNegotiationManager);
    exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.afterPropertiesSet();
    exceptionResolvers.add(exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver);
}

@Bean
public ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver() {
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
    messageConverters.add(getHttpMessageConverter());
    ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver = new ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver();
    exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    return exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver;
}
```

---

```
public class ErrorContentNegotiationStrategy implements ContentNegotiationStrategy {

@Override
public List<MediaType> resolveMediaTypes(final NativeWebRequest webRequest) {
    return Lists.newArrayList(Globals.JSON);
    }
}
```

I am getting this exception when the spring starts up.

```
No qualifying bean of type      [org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationStrategy] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: errorContentNegotiationStrategy,mvcContentNegotiationManager
```

Doesn't work when I add a @Qualifier annotation to my ErrorContentNegotiationStrategy class and give it a unique name. Throws the same Exception.

If I remove @Compoenent annotation and leave the code as is, then ErrorContentNegotiationStrategy() method in ErrorContentNegotiaionStrategy is not getting called.

Did anyone face this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the [`@Primary`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) annotation to your `ErrorContentNegotiationStrategy` class:

> Indicates that a bean should be given preference when multiple candidates are qualified to autowire a single-valued dependency. If exactly one 'primary' bean exists among the candidates, it will be the autowired value.

This should at least solve the exception during startup.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your reply. It does resolve. But lets say I want to create multiple beans which extend ContentNegotiationStrategy, then how should I go about that /.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the issue, I found that I was trying to load 2 beans of same type ( which is what the error message says. One of the bean was actual implementation and other one was a Mock for test case. Since both resided in the same package @component scanned the base package and couldn't decide which one to load. I resolved the issue by using @profile, which helps in loading beans based on the profile you load. I used 2 profiles, one for testing and one for development.